# How to access laravel sessions variables in payu post request

Tags: php, laravel, session, payu

I'm having some problems trying to access variables sessions in the confirmation page used it by payu. In the post request I can access the variables sent from the gateway like this: `$state_pol = $_POST["state_pol"];` and no problem with that, I can stored the value in my data base, But when I try to do this `$email = Auth::user()->email;` when I do that I can't get any variable or stored values in the DB. I need to stored in the DB the cart Items and I'm using moltin Cart, so I need to do something like this:

```
foreach (Cart::contents() as $item) {

    $citem = new Ite;
    $citem->compra_id           =   $compra->id;
    $citem->id_product          =   $item->id;
    $citem->name                =   $item->name;
    $citem->val_uni             =   $item->price;
    $citem->image               =   $item->image;
    $citem->iva                 =   $item->tax;
    $citem->qty                 =   $item->quantity;
    $citem->val_total           =   $item->total();
    $citem->save();
}
Cart::destroy();
```

the methods `Cart::contents()`  and `Cart::destroy();`  don't work, but just in the payu request, I tried this with paypal request and everything works correctly and I'm using  the same code, I mean with the variables session.
Thanks in advance for the time and help.
I just realized that the problem is with eloquent too. I mean, I cannot get access to the DB, I cannot do something like this `$user = User::where('id','=',1)->first();` I tried with query builder but it didn't work.

Comment: Where are you accessing session in this code?

Comment: Hi, the Cart::contents() method returns an array of items stored in session. As I said, I'm using Moltin cart and I don't know if it could be the problem, but I tried to put a variable in session like this Session::put('key', 'value'); but didn't work. I appreciate any help. Thanks